# Cannot implicitly convert type IQueryable to ObjectQuery with nested collections

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm not able to figure out how to query nested/associated collections.

The scenario is:
1 group list is associated many candidates
Same group is associated with many tests
So in a collection of group each groups has two list associated.
I need to fetch all the tests which are associated to any and all the groups to which the logged in user is a member.

What I tried through below code shows *Cannot implicitly convert type IQueryable to ObjectQuery*

```
tests = db.Tests.Where
(t => t.OAS_Group.Candidates.All
    (c=>c.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be in the type mismatch between `tests` and the right hand expression. Do you need to assign it to the same variable? If so, can you change the type of `tests` to be `IQueryable`? Since `ObjectQuery` implements both `IQueryabl<T>` and `IQueryable` you should be able to.

```
IQueryable<Test> tests = null;

// some other assignment to tests

tests = db.Tests.Where
        (t => t.OAS_Group.Candidates.All
             (c=>c.UserName == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)
        );
```